# How to slurp a value in a file and assign this to a variable inside a puppet module

Tags: puppet

I'm pretty new to puppet and have run into an issue.

We have a proprietary home-grown API-based secrets management platform. We can either query the API directly or configure so that the secrets for that host are mounted to the root filesystem.

My problem is I can't figure out how to get that information within the context of a puppet module and into a variable so that I can use it. It seems you can't get stdout/stderr back from exec (or can you) otherwise this would be cake.

So for simplicity, let's say my secret is /etc/app/example/foo.

```
    $roles.each |$role| {
        case downcase($role) {
            'foo': {
                # SOMEHOW I NEED TO GET TOKEN FROM FILESYSTEM OR API CALL HERE
                $token = <GET TOKEN SOMEHOW>
                # here I need to do something with my value
                exec { "my description":
                       command  => '//bin/foo',
                       environment => ["TOKEN=${token}"]
                 }
```

This is basically what I need to do at a basic level. It doesn't matter if I call curl directly (preferred approach) or read a mounted file.

Thx for any help.

Comment: You would definitely want to use a custom function for this: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/custom_functions_ruby.html. That is what I used when I wrote the first bindings for Vault Enterprise to Puppet Enterprise, and it is still the valid approach now four years later.

Comment: Architecturally the custom function should receive inputs for the secret to query, and return the secret value. You can then use the returned value in your Puppet manifest. The custom function allows easy use of bindings to interact with the API. Feel free to ask a follow up question if you have difficulties with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> you can't get stdout/stderr back from exec (or can you) otherwise this would be cake.

You cannot capture the standard output or error of an `Exec`'s command for reuse, but Puppet's built-in [`generate()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#generate) function serves exactly the purpose of executing a command and capturing its output.  Normally that would run the command on the server, during catalog compilation, but if you want it to run on the client instead then you can [defer its execution](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/deferred_functions.html).  One of the primary purposes for deferring functions is for interaction with secret stores.

With that said, you might want to consider wrapping the whole thing up in a [custom resource type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/custom_resources.html).  That's maybe a bit more work (especially if you don't speak Ruby), but it's a lot more flexible, and it should make for cleaner and clearer code on the Puppet DSL side, too.